# Problemas al ejecutar Procedimiento almacenado dentro de un loop

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, .net-core

actualmente quiero consumir un procedimiento almacenado que tengo en una base de datos mysql, la aplicacion es .Net core. El procedimiento almacenado necesita unos parametros, el problema esta que cuando intento utilizar este  procedimiento desde la aplicacion en un foreach no hace absolutamente nada.

```
public bool Actualizar(string connectionStringSqlServer)
    {
        //obtener los registros que aun no se han actualizado en la base de datos 
        var result = ObtenerPagos(connectionStringSqlServer);

        if (result.Count != 0)
        {
            string connection = "#################";
            MySqlConnection mysqConexion = new MySqlConnection();
            mysqConexion.ConnectionString = connection;                              
            mysqConexion.Open();
           

            for (int i = 0; i < result.Count; i++ )
            {
                
                Persona resultPersona = ConsumirClienteCredit10Test(int.Parse(result[i].NumeroCedula), connection);

                MySqlCommand comando = new MySqlCommand();                   
                comando.Connection = mysqConexion;

               // comando.Parameters.Clear();
                comando.CommandText = "Pago"; //nombre del procedimiento almacenado
                comando.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;        
                
                comando.Parameters.Add("@IdCupo", (MySqlDbType)SqlDbType.Int).Value = resultPersona.IdCupo;
                comando.Parameters.Add("@Cedula", (MySqlDbType)SqlDbType.Int).Value = resultPersona.Cedula;
                comando.Parameters.Add("@ValorPresu", (MySqlDbType)SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = resultPersona.ValorMinimo;
                comando.Parameters.Add("@ValorSugerido", (MySqlDbType)SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = resultPersona.ValorProximo;
                comando.Parameters.Add("@ValorTotal", (MySqlDbType)SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = resultPersona.ValorTotal;
                comando.Parameters.Add("@ValorPagado", (MySqlDbType)SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = result[i].Valor;
                comando.Parameters.Add("@CodSucursal", (MySqlDbType)SqlDbType.Int).Value = 998;

                var resultadoPersona = comando.ExecuteNonQuery();
                
            }
            
            mysqConexion.Close();
            Console.WriteLine("Termino procedimiento almacenado");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("No contiene resultados");
        }

            return true;

    }
```

Comment: ¿Dónde está `result`?

Comment: Result de la operacion ? te refieres a lo que retorna comando.ExecuteNonQuery();

Comment: Me refiero al código que falta, utilizas la variable "result" y en la pregunta no se ve de dónde sale. Lo más probable es que el valor de esa variable sea nulo y por ende, lo que hay en el bucle nunca se ejecuta. Por lo mencionado, actualiza la pregunta para darte una mejor respuesta :D

Comment: Result es una lista de elementos, los cuales voy a ir recorriendo y actualizando por medio del procedimiento almacenado.

Comment: Cuando coloco break point se que esta entrando en el foreach.

Comment: ¿Has intentado quitarle el "transaction"? De acuerdo con https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/implicit-commit.html "Transactions cannot be nested", en el buen español: no se pueden anidar las transacciones.

Comment: SI ya lo intentado pero no actualiza nada la base de datos ni tampoco arroja errores. Cuando intento utilizar consumir el procedimiento por fuera del foreach funciona bien.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112852/discussion-between-fredyfx-and-jhon-alexander-jimenez-morales).

Answer (score 0):

Los resolvi utilizando await en cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();

```
try
            {
                MySqlConnection mysqConexion = new MySqlConnection();
                mysqConexion.ConnectionString = connectionMysqlcredi10;
                mysqConexion.Open();

                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
                cmd.Connection = mysqConexion;
                //cmd.CommandText = "InsertarUsuario"; //name stored procedure
                cmd.CommandText = "Pago"; //name stored procedure
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                for (int i = 0; i < result.Count; i++)
                {
                    
                        Persona resultClient = InformationClient(int.Parse(result[i].NumeroCedula), connectionMysqlcredi10);

                        cmd.Parameters.Clear();
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IdCupo", resultClient.IdCupo);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Cedula", resultClient.Cedula);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ValorPresu", resultClient.ValorMinimo);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ValorSugerido", resultClient.ValorProximo);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ValorTotal", resultClient.ValorTotal);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ValorPagado", result[i].Valor);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CodSucursal", 998);
                        cmd.Parameters["@IdCupo"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
                        cmd.Parameters["@Cedula"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
                        cmd.Parameters["@ValorPresu"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
                        cmd.Parameters["@ValorSugerido"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
                        cmd.Parameters["@ValorTotal"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
                        cmd.Parameters["@ValorPagado"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
                        cmd.Parameters["@CodSucursal"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;

                        int rowsAffected = await cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
                                               
                    
                }

                mysqConexion.Close();
              

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error en: " + ex);

                throw;
            }
```